# Remove array from array if there is certain value in Object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, lodash

I want to remove array which is inside of whole array if an object of its array has certain value. I searched the web and I saw removing object or array if it has certain value and I can't find that solves my problem.

I have objects of array which is again wrapped by array. It looks like below:

```
"products": [
    [
        {
            "product.name": "A",
            "remark.name": "Good"
        },
        {
            "product.name": "B",
            "remark.name": "Good"
        }
    ],
    [
        {
            "product.name": "A",
            "remark.name": "Bad"
        },
        {
            "product.name": "B",
            "remark.name": "Good"
        }
    ]
]
```

**What I want**

I want to omit the whole array which contains **at least** `remark.name === Bad`
So, I should get the final result like below.

```
"products": [
    [
        {
            "product.name": "A",
            "remark.name": "Good"
        },
        {
            "product.name": "B",
            "remark.name": "Good"
        }
    ]
]
```

**What I've tried**

Below code

```js
let result = [];
products.map((product) => {
    var res = _.remove(product, function (n) {
        return n["remark.name"] === "Fail";
    });

    result.push(res);
});
```

produces following result:

```
"products": [
    [
        {
            "product.name": "A",
            "remark.name": "Good"
        },
        {
            "product.name": "B",
            "remark.name": "Good"
        }
    ],
    [
        {
            "product.name": "B",
            "remark.name": "Good"
        }
    ]
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [Array#filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) for filtering and as filter [Array#every](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) where remark.name is different from 'Bad'.

**Note:** Use single or double quotes for propertyname 'remark.name' because of the dot in it`s name.

```js
let products = [
    [
        {
            "product.name": "A",
            "remark.name": "Good"
        },
        {
            "product.name": "B",
            "remark.name": "Good"
        }
    ],
    [
        {
            "product.name": "A",
            "remark.name": "Bad"
        },
        {
            "product.name": "B",
            "remark.name": "Good"
        }
    ]
];

let filtered = products.filter(arr => arr.every(obj => obj['remark.name'] !== 'Bad'));
console.log(filtered);
```

Comment: Thanks. Perfectly works. Could you please explain why should single quote be used because of dot in property name?

Comment: @HtetPhyoNaing `obj.remark.name` implies `obj = { remark: { name: 'Bad' } }` while `obj['remark.name']` implies `obj = { 'remark.name': 'Bad' }`

Comment: You are right doublequotes works too. The only way what not functions is object.remark.name because this would be the property remark and there the property name.

Comment: So if not absolutely necessary avoid propertienames with a dot inside, it could result in missunderstoodness and faults.

Comment: Thank you all so very much. Understood.